# Lookup a cell in an Array and get the value of the adjacent cell?

Tags: excel, function

I am looking for formula that can help me to get the value of the adjacent cell if one cell is matched to my condition. E.g. Lookup the Range A1:D10, if there is a cell with string "DUE DATE" (cell C5 for example) then get the value of the next cell, D5.

I am thinking about the CELL("address") function but don't know what to do.

Please help! Many thanks for reading my post.

Sincerely

Comment: Will there only ever be one cell which matches your condition within that range?

Comment: Yes, there is only one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your choice of search value in F1:

`=INDEX(A:D,SUMPRODUCT((A1:D10=F1)*ROW(A1:D10)),1+SUMPRODUCT((A1:D10=F1)*COLUMN(A1:D10)))`

We could employ a slightly shorter construction involving INDIRECT, though there's no real reason to introduce volatility here.

Regards